# Calling Objective-C class in Swift class

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a project based on **Objective-C**. I have created bridging headers for **Swift** and can successfully call **Objective-C** files there. However I can not import `AppDelegate.h` in the new **Swift** file. Here what I try:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
#import "AppDelegate.h";
```

it returns error:

> Expected identifier in import declaration

How to import that?

Comment: Did you check [How do I call Objective-C code from Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24002369/1187415)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import any Obj-C files/headers in Swift. All Swift types will be able to see all Obj-C files that were added to the bridging header.